# Rail 7 - javascript button click in interval - turbo problem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have Javascript problem right now ( or turbo? )

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/rooms/broadcast_setted_for? 
room_id=24&amp;user_id=1" 
data-remote="true">

<button id="checkbtntoXf6" 
type="submit">update</button>

<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" 
value="hnnwlVNfD5BNQmoQEw78GJ8pJf4bIDPufMIzGG3- 
cgYlfkIyhXUWS5itaRvLBxbl0B7_frTy3Ni6F9fLKvHwOA" autocomplete="off">

</form>
```

When i click this button "manualy" everything works ok - partial is replaced from broadcast_setted_for ... but when I put this code in application.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.querySelector('#checkbtntoXf6');
const clickButton = () => {
  button.click();
}
setInterval(clickButton, 5000);
});
```

because I want this button to be clicked in interval - I see error:

`Form submission canceled because the form is not connected`

When URL is changed without page refresh.

Comment: Attaching an event handler directly to the elements on DOMContentLoaded is just not an approach that works when you're dealing with Turbo. Your event handler will only be attached to the element if its present on the initial page load. Instead you need a [delegated event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) attached to the document or a parent element (like body) that is not replaced when Turbo changes the page contents. This is what [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/origin) does.

Comment: `setInterval` is also considered harmful. It doesn't actually wait to see if the previous callback was completed so you could get a bunch of requests stacked up and then when it comes to the time to update the DOM it's not necissarily the last request to be responded to that wins. If you want to setup polling you want to use `setTimeout` instead to call the same function recursively after the previous request completed. But I have no idea why you want to now that turbo makes it so easy to stream from a websocket.

Comment: so I need to delegate event and use stimulus to do that?are you able to give some simple example or is it rather impossible by answering here ... Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok I did it with chatGPT ;-) ... first time user must click button "manualy" but I will make some "join to room" button which will be display:none after click ... thanks for comment, chatGPT create asnwer reading it ;)